# How to disable nginx access log by response header

Tags: nginx

I want to turn off the access log using the response header .

As in the following set .

You do not want to output a log when there is a header .

It does not work .

```
server {

   listen       80;
   server_name  localhost;

   access_log  logs/access_debug.log  debug_val_format if=$logging;
   set $logging 1;
   if ( $upstream_http_logoff ){
     set $logging 0;
   }
```

Response headers are sent .

```
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:5
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 11 May 2016 12:04:57 GMT
logoff:1
Server:nginx/1.7.11
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `map`:

```
map $upstream_http_logoff $logging {
  default 1;
  1       0;
}
```

Maybe you should consider to inverse upstream logic, so it would be easier to understand:

Upstream header `logging:0`

```
map $upstream_http_logging $logging {
  default 1;
  0       0;
  1       1;
}
```